# How to setup Cisco 7945 with two lines from different Asterisk servers?

Tags: voip, asterisk

I have a phone line with 192.168.3.10 Asterisk IP Server, and another phone line with 192.168.3.11 Asterisk IP Server.
Now I want to setup 900 from the first server and 500 from the second server on my Cisco 7945G.
I am OK when config lines from one server, But I cannot config lines from different servers.
How must I config the SEP***.cnf.xml file? Where should I write the IP servers?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup any number of accounts(upto number allowed by your firmware, can be upto 6) using TFP provisioning. Each account may have different proxy.

For more info about provisioning check cisco.com resources.
Part of file is following:

```
<sipLines>
    <line button="1">
       <featureID>9</featureID>
       <featureLabel>115</featureLabel>
               <name>115</name>
               <displayName>115</displayName>
               <contact>115</contact>

       <proxy>192.168.0.2</proxy>
       <port>5060</port>
       <autoAnswer>
          <autoAnswerEnabled>2</autoAnswerEnabled>
       </autoAnswer>
       <callWaiting>3</callWaiting>

       <authName>115</authName>
       <authPassword>S33krit</authPassword>

       <sharedLine>false</sharedLine>
       <messageWaitingLampPolicy>1</messageWaitingLampPolicy>
       <messagesNumber>*97</messagesNumber>
       <ringSettingIdle>4</ringSettingIdle>
       <ringSettingActive>5</ringSettingActive>

       <forwardCallInfoDisplay>
          <callerName>true</callerName>
          <callerNumber>false</callerNumber>
          <redirectedNumber>false</redirectedNumber>
          <dialedNumber>true</dialedNumber>
       </forwardCallInfoDisplay>
    </line>
    <line button="2">
       <featureID>9</featureID>
       <featureLabel>115</featureLabel>
               <name>115</name>
               <displayName>115</displayName>
               <contact>115</contact>

       <proxy>192.168.0.3</proxy>
       <port>5060</port>
       <autoAnswer>
          <autoAnswerEnabled>2</autoAnswerEnabled>
       </autoAnswer>
       <callWaiting>3</callWaiting>

       <authName>115</authName>
       <authPassword>S33krit</authPassword>

       <sharedLine>false</sharedLine>
       <messageWaitingLampPolicy>1</messageWaitingLampPolicy>
       <messagesNumber>*97</messagesNumber>
       <ringSettingIdle>4</ringSettingIdle>
       <ringSettingActive>5</ringSettingActive>

       <forwardCallInfoDisplay>
          <callerName>true</callerName>
          <callerNumber>false</callerNumber>
          <redirectedNumber>false</redirectedNumber>
          <dialedNumber>true</dialedNumber>
       </forwardCallInfoDisplay>
    </line>
 </sipLines>
```